# huge AWS RDS Data Transfer cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, data-transfer

I am using AWS RDS to host one of my client's MySQL database. His web server is hosted in a separate hosting company (TurnKey). This site has some 14,000+ unique visitors and ~270,000 requests per day. This is a WordPress driven site.

The question is Even though I am paying only 52 USD for RDS service I am getting some 150 $ bill for data transfer(For about 1560+GB per month). I understand that data transfer outside AWS is costly. I want to know if I host the web site in AWS in the same region (in a m4 or in a ec2), will it reduce the data transfer costs? Or is there any other option I can consider?

**Billing Summery**

```
Data Transfer
    US East (Northern Virginia) Region  - $141.39

RDS Service
    US East (Northern Virginia) Region  - $52.83
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Likely you should move the web server to AWS EC2 or move the RDS to Turnkey.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will not be charged this huge data transfer fee if you host your site on AWS because local AWS network traffic doesn't cost you anything.  It should also be a lot faster.

Comment: Instead, in that case, you'll pay for all of the content downloaded from the web site, which could be substantially *more* data than is transferred from the back-end to the app.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Highly unlikely, and also true of any hosting.  There will be a cost for hosting the application server(s) as well as costs for outbound transfer of data, even if there is a built in threshold that is part of the base hosting cost.  The question was not about alternatives or the relative cost of EC2 but rather, the exorbitant cost to move data between a front end server and a backend server.

Comment: Sure, it's true of any hosting, but in the context of a question of avoiding costs, it makes sense to include the added cost of the steps taken toward avoiding cost.  The argument could be made that if traffic between backend and frontend is *more* than traffic between frontend and browser, it seems like something isn't optimal.